# How to move entire headings in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

In documents, text can be a heading 1, heading 2, et cetera.

```
  heading1
     heading2
        heading3
          ...
```

For example:

```
 t1a
    abcd
       ...yyy
 t2a
    efgh
       ...xxx
    ijkl
```

I want to change it to this:

```
 t1a
    efgh
       ...xxx
    abcd
       ...yyy
 t2a
    ijkl
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **move entire chapters using the Navigator** in LibreOffice. To open the Navigator, hit **`F5`** or use **Menu `View` -> `Navigator`**. A small window will appear that will let you navigate between chapters, tables and so on:

[image: Navigator Window]

There's a [nice description in the LibreOffice Writer Wiki](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Rearranging_a_Document_by_Using_the_Navigator) how to rearrange chapter in Writer using the Navigator.

To do so (after activating the navigator):

1. **Open the content view**:

   [image: Navigator 3]
2. Either **drag the chapter to its new place**, or use the **four buttons** to promote / demote the chapter (move vertically) or to promote/demote the chapter's level (move horizontally):

   [image: Navigator 4]